# JQuery, AJAX, POST request, parameters lost

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

My web application is basen on Spring MVC (4.0.5).
I'm trying to send a POST request through AJAX, using jQuery (v. 2.1.1):

```
function deleteItem(id) {
    alert("Deleting " + id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/delete_item",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:  {"id": id},
        contentType: 'application/json',
            mimeType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                var txt = data;
                $('#message').html(txt);
            },
        error: function(data, status, err) {
            $('#message').html(err);
        }
    });
}
```

The Controller's method is called successfully but there are no parameters in the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/delete_item", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String ajaxDelete(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Enumeration<String> en = request.getParameterNames();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        String pname = en.nextElement();
        System.out.println("//// " + pname); // just for test
    }
    String idStr = request.getParameter("id");
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
    //...
```

Why the request parameter is lost? Not just the value, the parameter itself is also lost.
What's wrong here?

Comment: you need to add the tag for the Server side processing language.

Comment: The server-side is Java. What tag do you mean? Could you give more details, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing content type `contentType: 'application/json'` from **ajax** then add that settings in Spring method declaration as below: (  add `produces = "application/json"`  in definition)

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/delete_item", method = RequestMethod.POST , produces = "application/json")
  public @ResponseBody String ajaxDelete(HttpServletRequest request) {
```

also there's one more caveat that,

You are mentioning both **datatype  and mimeType** but it is not uniform.

`mimeType: 'application/json'` should be written with  `dataType: 'json'` and not **html**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what is wrong with your solution but I can give you an example that works for me

The AJAX request using Jquery :

```
 // Do AJAX
    $(function () {
        $.post(mobileUrl + "/leave/requestLeave",
            { startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, leaveTypeId: leaveTypeId,
                notes: notes, isStartDayHalfDay: isStartDayHalfDay, isHalfDayEndDay: isHalfDayEndDay },
            function (response) {
                $('#feedbackTextArea').show();
            }
        );
    });
```

And the controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestLeave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createOrUpdateNewForm(String startDate, String endDate, String leaveTypeText, String leaveTypeId,
                                        String notes, String isStartDayHalfDay, String isHalfDayEndDay) {

       startDate = new DateTime(startDate).toDate() etc

        }
    }
```

One thing to remember is that the parameter names in the ajax request should match the names of the variables in the controller method implementation

Answer (score -1):

```
    $("#drpop").change(function () {
     var code = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({ 
    url: '/Ordering/OrderingTable',
    type: 'post',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: { OperCode: code },
     success:function(msg){
alert(msg);
     } }); }); 
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult OrderingTable(string OperCode) 
    {
     Orderingbll order = new Orderingbll(); 
    var result = order.ListCategory(OperCode);//here you write your code
     return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: from where you came up with this answer? Non relative to this. may be wrongly mentioned here.